# How do I display hierarical data using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, listview, treeview

How do I display hierarical data in ASP.NET? I have a data source that looks like this:

```
class Tree
{
   IEnumerable<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}

class Node
{
   string Description { get; set; }
   decimal Amount { get; set; }
   IEnumerable<Node> SubNodes { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to render is as a list of divs, like the one below. I need the div tags to make the animations smooth when expanding and collapsing the branches.

```
<ul class="foldable">
   <li>
      <div class="line">
         <div class="description">...</div>
         <div class="amount">...</div>
      </div>
      <div class="line">
         <div class="description">...</div>
         <div class="amount">...</div>
      </div>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <div class="line">
              <div class="description">...</div>
              <div class="amount">...</div>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

- I tried building this using [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) elements, but I could not figure out how to call it recursively.
- I also looked at the [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.aspx) class, but dropped it because it is rendered using tables.
- I gave up on the [CSS Friendly Control Adaptors](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/) since this seems to be an either or switch for all the controls on the web site.
- I tried with a [BulledList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.aspx), but could not figure out how to make it render the divs.

I ended up using four identical nested ListView elements since I know that my lists are never deeper than four levels. But this solution is just so ugly that I'm hoping to find a better one here. =)

Comment: As an aside, try not to throw in loads of divs simply as layout containers - try to use HTML elements that match the semantics of your content first and apply CSS accordingly, using display: block if necessary - see http://daniiswara.net/2009/01/31/div-mania-is-not-semantic-xhtml/ - only use divs if you absolutely have to

Comment: Yeah, I know that this layout has a lot of divs. But it was necessary to get the animations right in all browsers. And this solution degrades nicely to a nested list if you turn off CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a repeater control and then cycle through your list and for each node that has children nest another repeater.  It would take some effort because your would need to use it programmatically, but having a prebuilt Repeater control as a server control would make it quite a bit easier.

I like using repeaters because they're VERY flexible when you take some time and work with them.  That, and they don't put in extraneous HTML. :)

Comment: Good point! I will move my code to the code-behind file if I don't get a better suggestion, because I actually like the point-and-click programming features that I get when editing markup files in Visual Studio.

Comment: If this is the case, then your best bet is nested ListViews, or getting some handy controls developer to develop a custom control for you that can perform your function.  Then you're able to use the Design Mode to set attributes.

Comment: But I can't have a recursive ListView? :'( That would have been such a beautiful solution.

Comment: You can recurse ListViews by nesting them in the front-end, but you must nest the datasources as well, which puts a hefty strain on your database.